# CSS transition on div element

Tags: css, css-transitions

easy question, why is the css transition in my example not working:

```js
$(function()
  {
      setTimeout(function()
                 {
                     $('#dr').addClass('testen');
                 }, 1000);
  });
```

```css
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
  border: 0px solid gray;
  background: gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: height 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: height 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: height 1.5s;
  -o-transition: height 1.5s;
  transition: height 1.5s;
}

.testen {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>hi</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="dr" class="dropdown">
      hi
    </div>
    <div style="height:1500px">
      height
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

the javascript is adding the css class ".testen" to the div element which is moving the element with margin-top and the element have css transition values, so why is it not working, it is instantly moving the div in my example without transition?

Comment: because you are changing margin and not height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation is looking for `height` but you are adjusting the margin.

```
.testen {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

I have updated your code below

```js
$(function()
  {
      setTimeout(function()
                 {
                     $('#dr').addClass('testen');
                 }, 1000);
  });
```

```css
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
  border: 0px solid gray;
  background: gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: margin-top 1.5s;
  -o-transition: margin-top 1.5s;
  transition: margin-top 1.5s;
}

.testen {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>hi</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="dr" class="dropdown">
      hi
    </div>
    <div style="height:1500px">
      height
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks know i understand this transition better